# How to apply XSL from another domain to XML

Tags: javascript, xml, xss, xslt

I have an XSLT file hosted `www.mydomain.com/myxslt.xls` which I want to apply to XML displayed on `subdomain.mydomain.com`. The cross-site scripting restrictions in the browsers prohibit me from loading the XSLT from the other domain. For various reasons, it is not desirable to host the XSLT on the sub-domain.

How do I go about importing the XSLT server side and rendering it and displaying it on the sub-domain? Can I do this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

Your web server serving subdomain.mydomain.com can most likely be configured to act as a proxy for the specified file. E.g. using Apache mod_proxy the following line would do the trick

```
ProxyPass /myxslt.xls http://www.mydomain.com/myxslt.xls
```

Comment: Thank you! Would I then refer to the document as 'myxslt.xls' only and not 'http://www.mydomain.com/myxslt.xls' anymore?

Comment: In the web pages or web responses on the subdomain you can refer to either subdomain.mydomain.com/myxslt.xls, /myxslt.xls or a relative path (e.g. myxslt.xls) just as you would any other resource available on the subdomain. The proxied resource can be used just as if it was actually hosted on the subdomain.